# Is it possible to dynamically generate Spock test methods?

Tags: groovy, spock

I have a lot of repetitive tests and I would like to abstract them somehow. Helper methods have been useful, but up to a point. I would be able to remove a lot of copy-paste code if I could somehow programmatically generate test methods in my `Specification`.

Concretely, I am testing the methods of an RPC layer. Most of the methods must fail if they are not called in a certain way. So I have Spock test methods like:

```
def observer = Mock(StreamObserver)
def rpc = new UserServiceRpc()

def "draftToOutbox: should fail when called without parent"() {

    def request = draftToOutboxRequest().toBuilder().clearParent().build()

    when:
    rpc.draftToOutbox(request, observer)

    then:
    1 * observer.onError(_)
    1 * observer.onCompleted()
}

def "outboxToDraft: should fail when called without parent"() {

    def request = outboxToDraftRequest().toBuilder().clearParent().build()

    when:
    rpc.outboxToDraft(request, observer)

    then:
    1 * observer.onError(_)
    1 * observer.onCompleted()
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not fluent in Groovy's metaprogramming (compile-time AST transform) features and am not sure how this might be done, whether it is possible, and whether this is a good idea. On one hand I have some copy-paste, but on the other hand my tests are quite readable. I would be inclined to have the best of both worlds, though: readability without the copy-paste.

Comment: Since Spock relies heavily on AST transformations, I wouldn't think generating test methods would be possible without building your own AST transformations to do so.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically the crux of my question. But certainly I'm not the first person to run into this issue. I could attempt to re-architect this so that I only have to test this in one spot, but that's not easy in this case because I'm using gRPC Java and it won't let me configure filters before my RPC methods. And I really want to test this for all methods!

Comment: @cjstehno So you think I'd have to write a compile time AST transform? Do you think the result would be readable?

Comment: Sounds like you could also generate the source code as an alternate approach. It might be easier than digging into Spock's ASTs.

Comment: Groovy AST transforms generally read like Egyptian Hieroglyphics.

Comment: Hmm that's not something I considered because: Java. But that's interesting. I'd prefer readable tests to readable implementation. But I'd probably keep my copy-pasta for now and see where it takes me, before generating Java code :)

Comment: > "Groovy AST transforms generally read like Egyptian Hieroglyphics." — as I suspected. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case you could use [Data Driven Testing](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/data_driven_testing.html)  with some groovy stuffs like this:

```
@Unroll
def "#method: should fail when called without parent"() {
    given:
    def request = "$methodToGetRequest"().toBuilder().clearParent().build()
    when:
    rpc."$methodToTest"(request, observer)
    then:
    1 * observer.onError(_)
    1 * observer.onCompleted()

    where:
    methodToTest    | methodToGetRequest
    'draftToOutbox' | 'draftToOutboxRequest'
    'outboxToDraft' | 'outboxToDraftRequest'
}
```

**EDIT**

An example using method pointer:

```
@Shared
String subjectToTest

def setupSpec() {
    subjectToTest = "sTring To Test"
}

def "test using method pointers"() {
    when:
    def result = methodPointer()
    then:
    result == expectecResult
    where:
    expectecResult   | methodPointer
    'STRING TO TEST' | subjectToTest.&toUpperCase
    'string to test' | subjectToTest.&toLowerCase
}
```

Comment: Yes that would be beautiful except I am testing `void` methods

Comment: In your case, the given block would be just `rpc."$methodName"(request, observer)` and in expect block you would check the mock iteration.

Comment: I didn't think I could do interaction tests in the expect block of a data table. And I need to test the interactions with the observer per my question.

Comment: Oh so in the "expect" block before the "where" table I can assert the observer interactions? I will try this! Thank you.

Comment: I updated the answer to give you an exact example. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, helped reduce a ton of code. Do you know whether it's possible to pass the methods themselves, like with `&` (http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#method-pointer-operator). I've tried and have gotten various errors.

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky I never tried to use method pointer on where block with data tables. I'm gonna try it and give you feedback later! It's really a interesting idea.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like when the method gets passed as a `Closure` it closes over a field that is still `null` at the time of passing. The field gets assigned later, but is null when the passed-in method gets executed. (To pass the method I have to do `this.&method`. Without `this` it doesn't know what I'm referencing)

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky yes you're right. So I instantiated the object on the setupSpec method. And it worked! I added the method pointer example too.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I looked again at the data tables docs and, indeed, anything in a `where:` block must be `@Shared` (or declared literally in-line) to work.